# Vue.js--TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null when doing canvas

Tags: vue.js, canvas

I'm trying to do canvas on Vue drawing a rectangle, it showed error below first, then somehow at some time it worked, but when i added another rectangle, it showed same error again. I'm confused. 
[

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at VueComponent.draw (canvass.vue?0b9f:25)
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"0ff045da-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/canvass.vue?vue&type=template&id=783d8a8a&scoped=true& (app.js:1258), <anonymous>:12:11)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3542)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972)
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCF2S.png)

Also, i tried to use the `let canvas = this.$refs.myCanvas` instead of the `getElementById` method thinking it might work, but no luck.

```
<canvas id="canvas" ref="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" v-on="draw()"></canvas>

draw() {
      let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
      let c = canvas.getContext("2d");
      c.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
      c.fillRect(100, 50, 30, 30);
    }
```

Comment: The issue is with your use of `v-on="draw()"`. What is it exactly you're trying to do there? What events are you trying to bind to?

Comment: In fact, I don't think that's a valid value for `v-on`. When used with no event type, `v-on` expects an object

Comment: Thanks @Phil, your comment makes sense. I'm a newbie front-end self learner, making silly mistakes. I got rid of the `v-on="draw()"`, and added `mounted: function(){this.draw()}`, and it worked. But first i tried 'created` in stead of `mounted` but didn't work, no idea why though.

Comment: `created()` runs before any HTML elements are rendered

Answer (score 1):

Phil has the correct answer. The created lifecycle hook is rendered before the html and the canvas will not be loaded.

You have to call the draw in the mounted hook:

```
<canvas id="canvas" ref="myCanvas" width="300" height="200" </canvas>

mounted: function () {
 this.draw();
},

draw() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
  let c = canvas.getContext("2d");
  c.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  c.fillRect(100, 50, 30, 30);
}
```